# PHP: Extend authentication class by methods of childs

Tags: php, class, authentication, parent-child

I'd like to declare a class auth that is extended by multiple child classes.

```
// Parent class that should be called
abstract class auth
{
    // Force child classes to implement this method
    abstract public function authUser($uid, $pw);
}

class configAuth1 extends auth
{
    public function authUser($uid, $pw)
    {
        // Do some authentication stuff
        return false;
    }
}

class configAuth2 extends auth
{
    public function authUser($uid, $pw)
    {
        // Do some authentication stuff
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to call the parent class and try all child class methods `authUser()` until one returns true.

So I'd say it's not senseful to instantiate all childs manually.
How can I handle this?

**UPDATE**

Currently I solve this with `get_declared_classes()` and `ReflectionClass`. Is this solvable on a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Parent class should not know about own children. Reflection API and related functions are not a good choice to implement a high level logic.
In your case, you can use a something like [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.

First, we declare generic interface of authentication method:

```
/**
 * Common authentication interface.
 */
interface AuthStrategyInterface
{
    public function authUser($uid, $pw);
}
```

Next, we add a some custom implementations of this interface:

```
/**
 * Firsts implementation.
 */
class FooAuthStrategy implements AuthStrategyInterface
{
    public function authUser($uid, $pw)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Second implementation.
 */
class BarAuthStrategy implements AuthStrategyInterface
{
    public function authUser($uid, $pw)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then we create yet another implementation that holds a collection of specific strategies.
Its `authUser()` method in turn passes authentication parameters to every inner strategy until one returns true.

```
/**
 * Collection of nested strategies.
 */
class CompositeAuthStrategy implements AuthStrategyInterface
{
    private $authStrategies;

    public function addStrategy(AuthStrategyInterface $strategy)
    {
        $this->authStrategies[] = $strategy;
    }

    public function authUser($uid, $pw)
    {
        foreach ($this->authStrategies as $strategy) {
            if ($strategy->authUser($uid, $pw)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's not the only way to solve your problem, but just an example.

Comment: Thank you. In this case I need to add an instance of every child class - isn't this automatically possible?

Comment: That task may be resolved by many ways too. Chosen method depends on your application design. For example, read about [Service Locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) and [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Also, automatic creation and binding of instances are often called "Autowiring" and this feature provided by many libraries and frameworks.